# How to save a variable in a local file using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to using Http for saving the value of a string in a local file. but it didn't work and I have not found information about how to do that operation.
Thanks for helping me.

```
let mystring = "My string";
this.http.post('../../assets/tracing.config', mystring);
```

Comment: So you want it on client side or server side....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)

Comment: I want it from the client side

Comment: Than what does http client has to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this npm

```
npm install file-saver --save
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';


obj = {
    ...
};


const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(obj)], {type : 'application/json'});
saveAs(blob, 'test.json');
```

If you want to save data using `node.js`

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/fileName.json", myData, function(err) {
if(err) {
    return console.log(err);
}

console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```